# Syntax error in PHP Twilio API

Tags: php, html, json, twilio, twilio-api

I followed instructions on this [website](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/11/increase-app-downloads-with-mobile-app-distribution-powered-by-twilio.html) and I have an error in my sendnotifications.php file, I don't receive the sending confirmation and messages "message sent" and "message not sent" don't display on my screen.

Everything works for the SMS, I receive it on my phone.

Here the PHP file:

```
<?php
// Required if your environment does not handle autoloading
require __DIR__ . '/Twilio/autoload.php';

// Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = ‘MyAccountSID’;
$token = ‘MyToken’;
$client = new Client($sid, $token);
$phone=$_POST["phone"];

// Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
$client->messages->create(
    // the number you'd like to send the message to
    $phone,
    array(
        // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
        'from' => ‘MyTwilioNumber’,
        // the body of the text message you'd like to send
        'body' => « MyMessage »
    )
);

// Display a confirmation message on the screen
$sms_check=’OK’; //Use Twilio’s callback here
$return_json = ‘{"sms_sent":"’ . $email_check . ‘"}’;

echo $return_json;

?>
```

Here my HTML form:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[///////////Javascript
    $(function(){
    $("#frm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("sendnotifications.php", $("#frm").serialize(),
    function(data){
    if(data.sms_sent == 'OK'){
    alert("Message Sent");
    } else {
    alert("Message Not Sent");
    }
    }, "json");
    });

    });
    // ]]>
    </script>
    </head>

<html>

<form id="frm" name="frm">
<input type="hidden" name="ajax" value="1" />
<input type="phone" name="phone" />
<button type="submit">Get Link</button>
<div class="error" style="display: none;"></div>
</form>

</html>
```

Here the error in Visual Studio Code:

```
{
    "resource": "/Users/Joris/Desktop/Test envoi sms accueil/sendnotifications.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undefined",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "syntax error, unexpected '{'",
    "startLineNumber": 31,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 31,
    "endColumn": 1.7976931348623157e+308
}
```

Here the error on Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sms_sent' of null
    at Object.success (source.html:10)
    at b (jquery.min.js:124)
    at XMLHttpRequest.x.onreadystatechange (jquery.min.js:129)
(anonymous) @ source.html:10
b @ jquery.min.js:124
x.onreadystatechange @ jquery.min.js:129
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
ajax @ jquery.min.js:130
post @ jquery.min.js:122
(anonymous) @ source.html:8
handle @ jquery.min.js:55
o @ jquery.min.js:49
```

Comment: First  up, before echoing `$return_json`, make sure the content type header is set with `header('Content-Type: application/json);`

Comment: Are you really using _curly_ single quotes all over the place, `‘...’`? - That is not correct PHP syntax, those need to be `'`

Comment: Your quotes in PHP code is invalid.

Comment: Smart Quotes, urgh! Well spotted. On a Mac these can be disabled somewhere in your keyboard preferences. What on earth are you coding in, MS Word? :-P

Comment: Haha, Visual Studio Code bur I copied and pasted the piece of code :D

Comment: you can use `json_encode()` for this line `$return_json = ‘{"sms_sent":"’ . $email_check . ‘"}’;`

Comment: @Sivabalan What do you mean by use this instead return_json, I replace all the line by : json_encode("sms_sent":"'.$email_check.'"); ?
I'm a noob

Comment: like this `echo json_encode(["sms_sent" => $email_check ]);` easily readable and proper way to do it

Comment: Thanks for syntax. But 'sms_sent' is still null in Chrome console

Answer (score 0):

The property was 'sms_sent' in HTML and 'sms_check' in PHP